# Imprimir String na vertical em Python

Tags: python, string

É um exercício que utiliza apenas strings, ainda não cheguei na parte de listas
Qual meu erro ?

```
print("-"*30)
nome = str(input("Digite seu nome: "))
cont = '0'
while cont < nome:
    c = int(cont)
    print(nome[c])
    cont += '1'
```

Comment: isto de ajudaria? ou  você precisa msmo declarar cont sendo string?   
print("-"*30)
nome = str(input("Digite seu nome: "))
cont = 0
tam=len(nome)
while cont<tam:
    c = int(cont)
    print(nome[c])
    cont += 1

Comment: Se ajudar ai sim coloco como resposta, senão seria apenas pra atrapalhar respostas melhores

Comment: Ótimo, essa está valendo... Tinha me esquecido do recurso "len". Obrigado cara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta concatenando string ao invés de somar na sua variável `cont` e não estava pegando o tamanho do `nome`

```
print("-"*30)
nome = str(input("Digite seu nome: "))
cont = 0 # era '0' string
while cont < len(nome): # aki coloquei len(nome) que é o tamanho
    c = int(cont)
    print(nome[c])
    cont += 1 # aki estava '1' string
```

https://repl.it/repls/GraveCadetblueOutput

---

Como foi comentado por @AndersonCarlosWoss, você esta utilizando o `python 3.x` então você não precisa converter o retorno do `input()`

```
# nome = str(input("Digite seu nome: "))
nome = input("Digite seu nome: ") # ficando assim
```

Comment: Você não precisa converter a saída de `input` para `str.` No Python 3+ sempre será `str`

Answer (score 3):

Substitua todo o seu código por essa linha:

```
for c in input("Digite seu nome: "): print(c)
```

Não use o `while` para iterar sobre uma string, a forma mais simples de iterar por uma string é usando uma declaração [for](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
for item in String:
```

Ou então não itere, apenas [desempacote](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) e retorno da função embutida [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#input) como [argumentos posicionais](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-argument) para função [print()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print) e use um caractere `\n`, new line, como valor para argumento nomeado `sep`.

```
print(*input("Novamente digite seu nome: "), sep="\n")
```

<sup>Teste os dois exemplos no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/PrintVertical#main.py)</sup>

Retorno dos dois exemplos:

```
Digite seu nome: Augusto
A
u
g
u
s
t
o
Novamente digite seu nome: Vasques
V
a
s
q
u
e
s
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas se mostrar uma `string` na vertical. Para complementar, poderia ser feito de maneira muito simples utilizando um `for`, ficando dessa maneira:

```
print("-"*30)

# Utilização com python versão 2.7
for x in str(input("Digite seu nome: ")):
   print(x)

# Utilização com python versão 3+
for x in input("Digite seu nome: "):
   print(x)
```

Essa seria uma maneira mais simples e fácil de implementar.

Você pode ler mais sobre iteração de `string` em `Python` em: [artigo](http://excript.com/python/iterando-string-python.html) e [artigo](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~jpp/ip/teorica-11.pdf).

Comment: Você não precisa converter a saída de `input` para `str`. No Python 3+ sempre será `str`.

Comment: Verdade, mas como não foi especificado a versão forcei a conversão.  Irei alterar para servir para mais casos.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esta questão, basta implementar o seguinte código...

```
palavra = input('Digite uma palavra: ')

for c in palavra:
    print(c)
```